# getting the value of multiple radiobuttons on a different page in php

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to make a system for my school and some of the code is giving me a problem. i have a teachers page on which i input some details from a database and give a radiobutton with each record. when the user clicks submit it is supposed to go to a different page and put only the records into a differnt table for which the radiobutton was checked.
The code for making the radiobutton is

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery))
{

echo "<tr> <td>$row[Name]</td><td> $row[Number]</td><td>$row[Form]</td><td> $row[Outings_left]</td><td>$row[Night_outings_left]</td> <td><input type='radio' id='$c' name=' $c' value='checked' /></td><td><input type='date' id='$sd' name='$sd' /></td><td><input type='date' id=' $ed ' name=' $ed' /></td></tr>";

$arr= Array($n=> Array(1=>'row[name]', 2=> 'row[number]') );
$c++;   
$sd++;
$ed++;  
}
```

Note- there are also two date fields getting the values in a similar manner

on the other page i am trying to check whether the radiobutton is checked in teh following manner. but this is showing that all the radoibuttons are unchecked

```
$cb1=$_POST['$c'];
    echo $cb1;
    if($cb1=='checked')
    {
        echo "entered";
}
```

Comment: Use a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's actually being passed to the form. `$cb1=$_POST['$c'];` is looking for a form field called `$c` - I'm assuming it's supposed to be a number instead. Remove the single quotes around `'$c'` and it should work as you expect

Comment: i tried to remve the quotes but the error still persists. Is there anything else that could cause the problem?

Comment: Did you try the var_dump? What variables is your form sending? What variables is your PHP page expecting?

Comment: Thanks it was clash in with the date inputs as they had the same id as the radiobutton. i have made unique ids now. Also could you please help me as to how i can get the selected date value from teachers.php into a php variable in teachersrdr.php to store in a MySql table?

Comment: Why doesn't the code you have work?

Comment: The code is working for checking whether the radiobutton is checked. The values from the date inputs are still not coming correctly into PHP variables though the code i am trying to use for that is $startdate=$_POST[$sd];
 echo $startdate;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Also, does every variable start at 1? If so, $c = $sd = $ed. So you are having multiple radio inputs with the same id and name.

Comment: Also, does every variable start at 1?  If so, $c = $sd = $ed.  So you are having multiple radio inputs with the same id and name.

Comment: Yes i realised that and i made the change. Gave each a unique Id by incrementing with prime numbers to avoid clashes. it is working now. Also could you please help me as to how i can get the selected date value from teachers.php into a php variable in teachersrdr.php to store in a MySql table?

Comment: He doesn't need to concatenate - that string is delimited by double quotes, so the `$c` will be correctly interpreted. The problem is the one you mentioned in your comment - there are multiple fields all named `1`.

Comment: Yeah. I only took a quick first glance then noticed the variables were all probably the same.  Glad it helped siddhant.

Comment: yes. the first part is in teachers.php where i am making the design. the working is heppening in teachersrdr.php. i am trying to get the dates from the fields where the radiobuttons are checked. the code i am using to get the dates is
 $startdate=$_POST[$sd];
echo $startdate;
This does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you put $sd in single quotes?  Try $startdate = $_POST['$sd'];  Just first thought.  Let me know if that doesn't help.

Comment: i tried it both ways but it is not working. Nothing comes into the $startdate variable.

Comment: Well $sd is going to be a number of values since you increment it.  My guess is that it's taking the highest value. (as in the last date field)  As an example, if $sd gets incremented to a value of 4, it's taking the value of <input type='date' id='4' name='4' />

Comment: Can you try to place a date in the last available date field and see if it moves the value to the teachersrdr.php page?  (Sorry for the delay in the response.  I got called into a short impromptu meeting)